# Adding a file on existing zip file using batch

Tags: batch-file, zip

Hi adding file on existing rar file using batch is working but .zip file doesn't support winrar so what is the other way to do this? Thank you.

Here's the code of batch file adding file on existing .rar [Add a single file to each rar file in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32450112/add-a-single-file-to-each-rar-file-in-a-folder/32450475#32450475)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-batch) and the [zipjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/zipjs.bat) :

```
// adds content to a zip file
call zipjs.bat addToZip -source C:\some_file.txt -destination C:\myDir\myZip.zip\InzipDir -keep no
call zipjs.bat addToZip -source  C:\some_file.txt -destination C:\myDir\myZip.zip
```

**Update**

if you want to execute this over all zips in a directory:

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\Users\userss\Downloads\Folder\"
for %%a in (*zip) do (
  call zipjs.bat addToZip -source "readme.txt" -destination "%%~fa"
)
popd
```

Comment: @ImNotAwesome you can get the zipjs.bat from the second link and just need to put it in the same directory as the bat which adds the content to the zip.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. I did that so the problem is the code.
`-destination C:\Users\Userss\Downloads\Folder\*.zip\InzipDir` 
I'm trying to add a file on every zip on the folder, so is this the error? Thanks

Comment: @ImNotAwesome - to process every zip you'll need for loop  e.g. `for %%a in (*.zip) do some command "%%a"` . The `InzipDir` is a direcotry in the zip you neef to be sure that exists.

Comment: `call zipjs.bat 
for %%a in ("C:\Users\userss\Downloads\Folder\*.zip") do addToZip -source C:\Users\userss\Downloads\Download\readme.txt -destination`

Comment: you're awesome and i'm not. thank you so much. i'm not really used to this.